# PHP: parse string in format yW into a timestamp

Tags: php

I have a string in the format yW. Year followed by the week number. I would like to get a timestamp. I am using Php 5.2.17 on Windows.

`strtotime()` does not seem to be working reliably. For the string '1142' it should return the first day of the 42nd week of 2011.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go, will work on windows also...

```
$date = '1201';
$y = substr($date, 0, 2) + 2000;
$w = substr($date, 2);
$ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $y) + ($w * 604800);
```

subtract 1 from week if week 1 is the first week of the year

Comment: This does not calculate the correction, see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Calculation ISO Week Date calculation examples.

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime()` does not accept that particular format. However, it can work with year and week number values if they're formatted as `2011W42`.

```
// Convert 1142 to 2011W42
$reformatted = '20'.substr_replace('1142', 'W', 2, 0);
$timestamp   = strtotime($reformatted);
```

See [*Compound Formats*](http://php.net/datetime.formats.compound) for details on this particular format.

Another option is the [`setIDODate()`](http://php.net/datetime.setisodate) method on the `DateTime` class.

```
sscanf('1142', '%2d%2d', $year, $week);
$date = new DateTime('@0');
$date->setISODate(2000 + $year, $week);
$timestamp = $date->format('U');
```

Comment: Very elegant and should be more efficient :)